# 1 node in rabbitmq cluster taking more load than other 2

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmq-shovel

I wanted to know if there is any way to distribute the loads evenly accross each nodes in a rabbitmq cluster.
I have a rabbitmq cluster with 3 nodes in it and my 2nd node is consuming around 70% and sometimes 100% of CPU usage, where as my other 2 nodes don't even go above 30%.
I wanted to fix this issue as soon as possible. I would really appreciate your help. thank you.

I tried adding ha-all policy. Expected it to distribute load, but it didnt.